# Jquery error on $.each

Tags: jquery

I don't understand why my jquery is in trouble here :

```
function setDelay(id){
    console.log($(json.attributes));
    $.each(json.attributes,function(k,v){
        if (k == id){
            alert(v.options.delivery_delay);
        }

    });
```

The console.log is well returning my json, but the line after throw this :

```
TypeError: $.each is not a function


$.each(json.attributes,function(k,v){
```

Any idea?

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have jQuery included to me. or `$` isn't jQuery.

Comment: version : Jquery 1.7.1

Comment: @kevin if i had not jquery included, i should bug on the line before : 
    console.log($(json.attributes));

Comment: Not necessarily. jQuery isn't the only library that makes use of `$`. Many older applications pre-2008 even defined a function named `$` who's sole purpose was to select an element by id. Many since then define one named `$` that simply pass the string to the css selector engine, which would give very similar results to jQuery when logged to console.

Comment: Do you have other libraries included that may be conflicting with "$" ? Does it error if you do jQuery.each ?

Comment: @NicolasD Give me the output of: `console.log($.toString(), $.fn && $.fn.jquery);`

Comment: Add `jQuery.noConflict();` and try using jQuery.each. If you still receive the  error include the jquery library.

Comment: Well done guys, it was the $ already used by some other library, corrected by using jQuery instead of $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was the $ already used by some other library, corrected by using "jQuery" instead of "$"

Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score -1):

`$` is probably defined as something else than jQuery somewhere in your code, prior to your `each` statement.

Try replacing `$.each` with `jQuery.each`.

Comment: Some other users already gave the answer and I wrote this in the comments above before you posted this

Comment: I'm glad that you resolved your problem. Next time, you can add your own accepted answer to your question, when it is resolved.